# iOS: What are the BLE pairing popup display rules

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm new to CoreBluetooth framework and I want to understand the rules behind Bluetooth connexion popups displayed by iOS. I have made some guesses, but I could not find any official documentation on this rules.

I understood that while developing a BLE Central role application, I have no control over whitch security popup will be displayed. I want to anticipate whitch popup will be displayed regarding the Peripheral device configuration.

During my tests with Apple BLE demo project `CoreBluetoothLESample`, I managed to activate the display of a pairing popup adding `.indicateEncryptionRequired` option to the characteristic options in the `PeripheralViewController` class:

```
let transferCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(
        type: TransferService.characteristicUUID,
        properties: [.notify, .writeWithoutResponse, .indicateEncryptionRequired],
        value: nil,
        permissions: [.readable, .writeable]
    )
```

**My question is:** Can I find a documentation about pairing popups display rules on central iOS device (just a "Cancel/Pair" popup without numeric comparison, popup with numeric comparison, popup asking to enter a PIN, or no popup at all) regarding peripheral security level and/or capabilities (can display a PIN or not) ?

Comment: If any characteristic of the peripheral requires encryption then the pairing/bonding process will be triggered the first time the central interacts with it.  The pairing dialog depends on the pairing modes supported by the peripheral.

Comment: @Paulw11, yes, I understood that, but I need to know whitch dialog will be displayed regarding the pairing mode. Do you know where I can find some documentation describing whitch pairing dialog will be displayed depending on the pairing modes supported by the peripheral ?